# "Рискованный человек" или "рисковый человек"?

Tags: грамотность, семантика

Как правильно: *рискованный человек* или *рисковый человек*?

Comment: there's an answer on the Gramota.ru website http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Ну наверное можно и для "рискованного человека" какой-то подходящий контекст выдумать, но вообще-то правильно будет "рискОвый человек".

Comment: Предложите пример для "_рискованного человека_", попробуем оценить :) . Мне пока в голову приходит только "человек, которым рискнули/рисковали", но так не говорят. Речь в любом случае должна идти о риске **не** со стороны "_рискованного человека_" - по форме это страдательное причастие как-никак: то ли это человек "из пробирки", которого рискнули выпустить в мир, то ли освобождённый по УДО, которого рискованно было выпускать, то ли ещё какой-то фантастический контекст. Но как-то не клеится.

Comment: @Alex_ander аргумент, но сказать то можно: *Рискованный ты, Василий Иванович, о-о-й рискованный, пробу уже на тебе ставить некуда.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В отношении людей употребляется только *рисковый*, а *рискованным* может быть только действие.

*Рисковый* can be used with regard to people, but  *рискованный* can be used only for  action.

Comment: Дело может быть и рисковым и рискованным.

Comment: @V.V., да, и мой ответ никак не конфликтует с этим утверждением)